# Nginx 403 error

Tags: nginx

I am having trouble with converting .htaccess files to nginx. I have 3 .htaccess files. The first .htaccess file is located in the document root and is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^img-(.*)\.html img.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^slide-(.*)\.html slider.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page-(.*)\.html page.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^contact\.html$ contact.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

The second .htaccess file is located in a folder called upload:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?foo\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ nohotlink.gif [L]
<Files ~ "\.(php|sql|php3|php4|phtml|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi)$">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

And the third and final .htaccess file is found in a subdirectory of the upload folder named "small":

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Now I have created a folder in /etc/nginx called includes and made 3 seperate .access files with these rewrite rules:

For the first .htaccess file located in the document root directory I have created an file in /etc/nginx/includes called root.access. In this file I have:

```
# nginx configuration 

location /img { 
rewrite ^/img-(.*)\.html /img.php?id=$1 break; 
} 
location /slide { 
    rewrite ^/slide-(.*)\.html /slider.php?id=$1 break; 
} 
location /page { 
    rewrite ^/page-(.*)\.html /page.php?name=$1 break; 
} 
location /contact { 
    rewrite ^/contact\.html$ /contact.php break; 
}
```

For the second file located in the "upload" folder I have crated a file in /etc/nginx/includes called upload.access. This file contains the following:

```
# nginx configuration 

location /upload { 
if ($http_referer !~ "^http://(.+\.)?foo\.com/"){ 
rewrite .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ /nohotlink.gif break; 
} 
} 
location ~ \.(php|sql|php3|php4|phtml|pl|py|jsp|asp|htm|shtml|sh|cgi)$ { 
deny all; 
}
```

And for the third and final file I have created a file in /etc/nginx/includes names small.access. The contents of this file are as follows:

```
# nginx configuration 

location /upload/small { 
}

In the server block configuration file I have:

 location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
              include /etc/nginx/includes/root.access;
     }

 location /upload {
              include /etc/nginx/includes/upload.access;
     }

 location /upload/small {
              include /etc/nginx/includes/small.access;
     }
```

Now with this configuration when trying the site I receive 403 errors. Nginx error log reports:

```
[error] 18156#0: *7 access forbidden by rule, client: 111.**.**.**, server: foo.com, request: "POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1", host: "foo.com", referrer: "http://foo.com/"
```

Now under apache everything works no problems. But I can not see why I am getting 403 errors. I am also worried that the rewrite rules as I have stated them, beyond the 403 error will not function properly at all. Can anyone help me with this? I can not see what is wrong here.